# Left Factoring using Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

Helllo,
I have the following syntax:

```
<attribute_value> ::= <spec_constant> | <symbol> | ( <s_expr>*)
<attribute>       ::= <keyword> | <keyword> <attribute_value>
```

by reading a [tutorial](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsing_expressions_and_statements), it says it's possible to use `buildExpressionParser` and it will perform Left-factoring, but there isn't an example.

Can someone give me an example on how i should parse the above syntax using Parsec or just point me in the right direction ?

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: What little of your grammar you have shown is not left-recursive, so it doesn't need left-factoring.

Comment: I don't know a lot about parsers, but isn't left factoring used to solve a First /First conflict? My question in `<attribute>` how does the parser knows which path to take between `<keyword>` and `<keyword> <attribute_value>`?

Comment: Left-factoring is required when the first match in a rule is the rule itself, which leads to an infinite loop in a recursive descent parser. Here, you just need to use `try` to allow the parser to backtrack over the `<keyword>` if it doesn't find the `<attribute_value>`, or make the `<attribute_value>` optional, and remove the `<keyword>`-only branch.

Comment: @Rogerp062 Backtracking isn't even necessary, here. Your attribute parser could be composed of a keyword parser, followed by an alternative: a parser for one attribute value, *or* a parser that returns a default value if the previous one (i.e. the parser for one attribute value) fails. In applicative style, it could be something like: `attribute = keyword *> (attributeValue <|> pure defaultValue)`. See the section entitled *Backtracking and its discontents* in [chapter 16 of Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html) for an example of this.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you already have

```
data Keyword
data AttributeValue

data Attribute = KeywordOnly Keyword
               | KeywordWithAttribute Keyword AttributeValue

keyword :: Parser Keyword
attributeValue :: Parser AttributeValue
```

then you can implement `attribute :: Parser Attribute` by first parsing the `Keyword`, then optionally parsing the `attribute`, then combining them:

```
attribute :: Parser Attribute
attribute = pack <$> keyword <*> optionMaybe attributeValue
  where
    pack :: Keyword -> Maybe AttributeValue -> Attribute
    pack kw = maybe (KeywordOnly kw) (KeywordWithAttribute kw)
```

without having to change the structure of your grammar.